# Is it possible to open and edit an Excel file on web browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm using MVC4 for web application and want to open an Excel file on web browser with editable functionality. Requirement is that end user Excel format is not fixed but our database column is fixed and I want to save Excel parameter in our database.

Is this possible?

Comment: Direct in-browser editing of Excel documents sounds like something one would develop in SharePoint, not in ASP.NET.

Comment: is it possible to only view  in asp.net?

Comment: I don't think view also is possible, IE might support but other browsers are not going to support the view. There are few plugin(grids) in javascript, which you can use to get a similar feel. check this out http://handsontable.com/

Comment: Yes you are right .I have searched out.. ActiveX plugin available but its only support to IE. Thanks for reply

Comment: try using EPPlus library, nice library. `http://epplus.codeplex.com/`

Comment: @PrashantMehta if you want to read the data from excel file, then i can help you with the sample code. which can be used with EPPlus library

Comment: yes Please provide me some sample code.it will be very helpful.....

Comment: thanks @pnuts for editing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [*EPPlus library*](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) you can try the following code. `path` is relative path of your excel file on server. First `foreach` loop is used for Header part and second `for` loop is for rest of the sheet. Most of the code is self explanatory.

```
    private DataTable getDataTableFromExcel(string path)
    {
        using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                pck.Load(stream);
            }
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            bool hasHeader = true;
            int headercol = 1;
            int rownumber = 1;
            try
            {
                foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(headercol.ToString());
                    headercol++;
                }
                var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;

                for (var rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
                {
                    var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, 38]; //last parameter is colums count, here i fixed it to 38 
                    var row = dt.NewRow();
                    foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                    {
                        row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    rownumber++;
                }
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
               // throw new Exception(x + " on row " + rownumber);
                return null;//Dont use null, But Log your exception here. 
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Shaminder for sharing code. It's really very helpful..

Comment: What's with that `catch` block?  Is returning `null` really the *only* alternative there?  Do you not want to even *look* at or *log* the exception?  And that commented-out line is just plain wrong, don't ever do that.

Comment: @PrashantMehta , try the code and let me know if any help needed

Comment: @David, yes david its not the production code, just wrote null there, but have used logger there in real code.

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla: Be aware that the commented-out line should never, ever be used.  Not in production, not in development.  It essentially throws away useful debugging information, which makes development unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: @David, the commented out line was used in debugging some error then, and th**nx for the concern and sharing valuable information.

Comment: This will only help reading the Excel file into a DataTable. That is not what the question is about as far as I can see.

Comment: @RuneGrimstad, i asked the OP in comments about sharing the reading code for excel, you should read the comments also. and moreover its one of the requirement of the OP.

Answer (score 4):

As Valerio Cassano suggests you may be able to get something working yourself. But it depends on how much editing you need and how complex your spreadsheets are.

To read out the data from an Excel File you can use a .Net component like EPPlus. It is quite fast and easy to use and lets you extract most of the data you need easily.

But to make the data visible and editable in a web page you need something more. There are some web (HTML/JS-based) components that lets you display tabular data in something that looks like Excel. Check out [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/) for instance. Using this together with EPPlus you should be able to read out the data from an Excel file, display it in a web page with some editing possible, and finally you would be able to submit those data back to the server and generate a new Excel file using EPPlus again.

It will require some coding, but it is absolutely doable.

Now, this will probably not support formulas and not figures/charts, but as long as your files only contain data and simple formatting you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Rune for quick reply. EPPlus is good component. I'm trying to show excel in html form on web browser.